# external API - JSON data does not accept "#" google sheets.

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets-api

I am using google sheets to pass Json data from an external API into more manageable sections. Using code in googlesheets to pass needed data at any given time. However when passing a name into the api, if the name contains a "#" i receive an error "cannot read property attack from undefined"

however if i manually enter the name into the API with the "#" it accepts it without a problem. the api is viewable here: https://ygohub.docs.apiary.io/?#reference/0/card-info/check-card-info?console=1 
I am passing values as such: =GetCardText(B18) 
B18 will work, as the cell contains the word "Mezuki"

however B19 will not as it contains "Mystical sheep #2"
My code:

```
function GetCardAttack(CardName) {

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.ygohub.com/api/card_info?name=" + CardName);
var w = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

return w.card.attack
```

}

Example of a card name that works: Mezuki

One that does not work: Mystical Sheep #2

Comment: What happens when you encode your cardname?  It might be subject to sql injection, but it has issues passing unencoded # into the URL because that is a keyword for uri.

Comment: Not sure i know how exactly to do that to be honest, i've just seen other special characters such as & also fail

Comment: you were correct, to fix this i added the line:
      var uri = CardName;
  var res = encodeURIComponent(uri);
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.ygohub.com/api/card_info?name=" + res